# How to deal with missing value input in dataset-Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data like this

```
8213034705_cst,95,2.927373,jake7870,0,95,117.5,xbox,3
,10,0.18669,parakeet2004,5,1,120,xbox,3
8213060420_gfd,26,0.249757,bluebubbles_1,25,1,120,xbox,3
8213060420_xcv,80,0.59059,sa4741,3,1,120,xbox,3
,75,0.657384,jhnsn2273,51,1,120,xbox,3
```

I am trying to put "missing value" to the first column where the records are missing ( or removing them altogether). I am trying to execute the following code but it is giving me error

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.log4j._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import java.lang.String
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
//import spark.implicits._


object DocParser2
{

 case class Auction(auctionid:Option[String], bid:Double, bidtime:Double, bidder:String, bidderrate:Integer, openbid:Double, price:Double, item:String, daystolive:Integer)

 def readint(ip:Option[String]):String = ip match
{

  case Some(ip) => ip.split("_")(0)
  case None => "missing value"

}





 def main(args:Array[String]) =
 {

   val spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("DocParser").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

   import spark.implicits._





   val  intUDF  =   udf(readint _)

   val lines=spark.read.format("csv").option("header","false").option("inferSchema", true).load("data/auction2.csv").toDF("auctionid","bid","bidtime","bidder","bidderrate","openbid","price","item","daystolive")

   val recordsDS=lines.as[Auction]

   recordsDS.printSchema()



   println("splitting auction id into String and Int")

   // recordsDS.withColumn("auctionid_int",java.lang.String.split('auctionid,"_")).show() some error with the split method

   val auctionidcol=recordsDS.col("auctionid")

   recordsDS.withColumn("auctionid_int",intUDF('auctionid)).show() 

   spark.stop()

 }

}
```

but it is through the following runtime error

> cannot cast java.lang.String to Scala.option in the line  val  intUDF 
>   =   udf(readint _)

could you help me figure out the error?

Thanks

Comment: Which spark version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

a UDF has never an `Option` as an input, but rather needs the actual type to be passed. In case of a `String` you can do null-check inside your UDF, for primitive types (Int, Double etc)  which can't be null, there are other solutions...

Comment: do you know of any way to remove missing value records?

Comment: althoug I'm not sure about spark 2.0, in 1.6 I would do something like this: `recordsDS.where(col(auctionId).isNotNull).withColumn("auctionid_int",intUDF('auctionid)).show()`

Answer (score 0):

You can read `csv` file with `spark.read.csv`, and use `na.drop()` to remove records that contain missing values, tested on spark 2.0.2:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header", "false").option("inferSchema", "true").csv("Path to Csv file")

df.show
+--------------+---+--------+-------------+---+---+-----+----+---+
|           _c0|_c1|     _c2|          _c3|_c4|_c5|  _c6| _c7|_c8|
+--------------+---+--------+-------------+---+---+-----+----+---+
|8213034705_cst| 95|2.927373|     jake7870|  0| 95|117.5|xbox|  3|
|          null| 10| 0.18669| parakeet2004|  5|  1|120.0|xbox|  3|
|8213060420_gfd| 26|0.249757|bluebubbles_1| 25|  1|120.0|xbox|  3|
|8213060420_xcv| 80| 0.59059|       sa4741|  3|  1|120.0|xbox|  3|
|          null| 75|0.657384|    jhnsn2273| 51|  1|120.0|xbox|  3|
+--------------+---+--------+-------------+---+---+-----+----+---+

df.na.drop().show
+--------------+---+--------+-------------+---+---+-----+----+---+
|           _c0|_c1|     _c2|          _c3|_c4|_c5|  _c6| _c7|_c8|
+--------------+---+--------+-------------+---+---+-----+----+---+
|8213034705_cst| 95|2.927373|     jake7870|  0| 95|117.5|xbox|  3|
|8213060420_gfd| 26|0.249757|bluebubbles_1| 25|  1|120.0|xbox|  3|
|8213060420_xcv| 80| 0.59059|       sa4741|  3|  1|120.0|xbox|  3|
+--------------+---+--------+-------------+---+---+-----+----+---+
```